# EntityFramework 4.0 Mapping Oracle to Designer Class

Tags: entity-framework-4

I've taken over a project in VS 2010 that uses .NET 4.0. It uses Entity Framework version 4.0. I'm wondering if I should upgrade to Entity Framework 6.0?

While mapping a new table, I noticed the previous developer set his columns on a table as Integer and mapped it to the designer class. However, upon closer look at the entity designer class (.cs) the result is INT32.

However when I created a table with similar specs my Integer column was mapped as decimal in the designer class.

So in a nutshell - it is mapping Oracle Integer to .NET decimal.

I can only guess that the previous developer used brute force to change the properties of each column in the visual EDMX file and set it to INT32.

I would have to select each column of my table in the visual design (EDMX) and ensure it is INT32 in the properties.

A bit tedious but has this been cleared up in EF 5.0 or EF 6.0 as a more straightforward mapping? INTEGER to INT32?

Has EF 5.0 or EF 6.0 cleared up the mapping?

I'm using Oracle 11G.

Answer (score 0):

After further research you can use Oracle NUMBER(10) which tranlates to INT32 on the .NET end.